# Splitting Strings in Informatica PowerCenter Designer

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am using Informatica and I would like to split a string based on the commas in the string and return everything before/after a comma to different ports/columns. For instance, I have the string

```
'Answer1, Answer2, Answer3'
```

being passed into an Expresssion Transformation and I would like for each value/answer to be passed into a different port/column. The problem I have is that sometimes the string being passed into the Expression Transformation has only one value ('Answer1') or two values ('Answer1, Answer2') or many values ('Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4, Answer5') but all I need are the first three values (or any 3 values) to be passed into the different ports/columns and if there is only one value, then the other 2 ports/columns should just be null.

I have no idea how to do this because I am not sure how to account for the different kind of strings that can be passed into the Expression Transformation, since sometimes there are no commas in the string and sometimes there are a lot of commas. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using REG_EXTRACT function, which extract parts of string based on regular expression patterns.

Let's say inp_ANSWERS is your input port in the expression transformation. Create 3 output ports with the following expressions:

```
out_ANS1:= REG_EXTRACT(inp_ANSWERS ,'([^,]*),?([^,]*),?([^,]*).*',1)
out_ANS2:= REG_EXTRACT(inp_ANSWERS ,'([^,]*),?([^,]*),?([^,]*).*',2)
out_ANS3:= REG_EXTRACT(inp_ANSWERS ,'([^,]*),?([^,]*),?([^,]*).*',3)
```

This will put the first 3 comma seperated values in the 3 ouput columns. If there are less than 3 values, the remaining columns will have blanks.